# Couldn't connect to the Box API due to a network error?

Tags: box, java

I am getting below mentioned error while accessing the box api using  box java sdk in java application.Please suggest the cause for this problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: Couldn't connect to the Box API due to a network error.
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.trySend(BoxAPIRequest.java:386)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:200)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:175)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxUser.getCurrentUser(BoxUser.java:112)
    at com.box.cdm.demo.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.trySend(BoxAPIRequest.java:384)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main causes of this exception - and the things you need to check - are:-

1. There is no network between your application (the client) and the server (the Box API). Where is the Box instance running, on same machine as your application (locally)?
2. What port is Box listening on? You need to show your connection code code (endpoint / port etc).
3. If client and server on different hardware, and you know you have a network connection between them then is Box behind  firewall?

Comment: Thanks.Client application network is behind the firewall.

Comment: Box listening on port number 443.

Comment: Should I want to enable port number 443 in application deployed machine?

Comment: The problem for me was firewall blocking the connection.